# Python How to use np.select to run different functions to modify global variables?

Tags: python, numpy, function, global-variables, vectorization

I am trying to run different sets of code based on conditions using code that is faster than multiple nested if statements. I did not know how else to do this than to reference four separate functions that each contain different code and define certain variables differently. The code below runs different functions depending on the conditions. The problem is, the functions define a bunch of variables that I need to use globally. When I set each variable to `global` within each of the four functions, the output was all messed up. But if I only set `global` to the variables within the specific function that is triggered by the conditions and not the other three functions, the output data is perfect.

How do I use np.select as shown below to define several variables differently based on conditions? Is there some faster way than np.select?
Attacking the problem from a different angle: How do I use multiple functions to define variables differently globally based on conditions? If conditions for one function are satisifed, the other three functions will not be triggered.

```
conditions = [
    ((PCount > 1) & (DCount > 1)),
    ((PCount > 1) & (DCount == 1)),
    ((PCount == 1) & (DCount > 1)),
    ((PCount == 1) & (DCount == 1)),
]

choices = [
    PMultipleDMultiple(),
    PMultipleDSingle(),
    PSingleDMultiple(),
    PSingleDSingle(),
]

np.select(conditions, choices, default='NA')
```

Thanks

I tried making `global` five variables in each of the four functions, but that caused the data in the variables to be messed up. When I remove `global` from the variables in the functions that are not triggered by the conditions, and only leave the variables as `global` within the function that is triggered by the conditions, the data comes out correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out:

At end of each of the four functions, I need to add `return Variable1, Variable2, Variable3, Variable4`

And add this at the end:

```
Variable1, Variable2, Variable3, Variable4 = np.select(conditions, choices, default='NA')
```